# Move OS backup to another machine

Tags: windows, backup, vmware, migration

I have installed `Ubuntu 17.04` as my primary `OS` on `PC`. 
Now I have to install `Windows` as primary OS due to several reasons. I want to backup now my `Ubuntu` and after installing `windows` on this `PC` I want to install `VMware` and run my backup image as it was before backing up, all files, all softwares and settings to be the same, is it possible?

Comment: I don't know vmware, but it is possible using clonezilla to do this with Virtualbox.

Comment: but as i mentioned right now linux is my primary os, so it's not in vm, it's on ssd, i ant to back it up from ssd and then run  in vm

Comment: You can do that with clonezilla, as  I said.  Backup your currrent install with clonezilla and restore it in a virtual machine.  I don't know about vmware but it will work in vbox, I've done it.